# IntelliJ IDEA - gradle not recognizing gradle kotlin dsl in build.gradle.kts

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a fresh install of IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Community Edition), Gradle 7.4, and Kotlin plugin 222-1.7.10-release-334-IJ3345.118 that is not recognizing gradle kotlin dsl. I am trying to run a Ktor project that I generated on the ktor website--so I am fairly sure that the syntax is correct. I haven't made any other modifications.

The error `e: /foo/build.gradle.kts:8:8: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)`

Which is erroring out in

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
    id "io.ktor.plugin" version "2.1.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.7.10"
}
```

on the 4th line of that snippet.

Is there something special I need to do to configure Intellij to recognize that build.gradle.kts is gradle kotlin dsl and not Groovy?

### Edit

As @aSemy pointed out, there is a Groovy vs Kotlin syntax mismatch that I had missed. Converting the first `id` to the second one fixed the syntax issue, but left me with a different issue

```
 /foo/build.gradle.kts:8:25: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: String?): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: Provider<String>): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

For my purposes, I decided to take out the library since it is described [on Github](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-build-plugins) to be for helping with Ktor deployments--but I'm only working locally.

Comment: `id "io.ktor.plugin" version "2.1.0"` is valid Groovy, but not valid Kotlin. You need to change it to `id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.1.0"`.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `plugins {}` block that is causing that second error?

Comment: To fix the problem change the third plugin declaration to `id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.1.0"`